# how to create a black rounded-corners window in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, custom-controls

How to create a rounded corners black window in cocoa? Is it standard and can be created by IB? Can somebody provide an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an NSPanel from the standard IB library.  It is dark gray and translucent (not black though), and has rounded corners.

Here is a screenshot: http://grab.by/45kJ

In the library it is referred to as a HUD Window.

Comment: An NSPanel is not necessarily a HUD window. Many other plain Aqua windows are actually panels, including the About panel, most Preferences panels, and all floating panels.